# Remove Strange Font Coding

Tags: php, html, fonts, unicode-normalization

Hi im hoping this is a simple issue I am loading some simple data via an API however some users have made their username's in fancy fonts as below.

How to do I convert this to a simple standard encoding using PHP so it would display as.

```
Web Reposts
```

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<?php
echo(Normalizer::normalize(" ", Normalizer::FORM_KC));
```

(If you want, you can use form KD instead of KC.) See https://secure.php.net/manual/en/class.normalizer.php for more details.